# What fee rate would offset the cost of RAM for a million nodes?

Tags: transaction-fees

When fees are low it's sometimes suggested that the minimum relay fee is lowered below 1 satoshi per vbyte. But transactions come with externalities (bandwidth, CPU, memory, disk space), both when they're in the mempool and after they're mined (block space, UTXO size). This question zooms in to the UTXO space usage.

Assuming there were 1 million nodes and each of them kept the entire UTXO set in RAM [0], what should the fee rate be to offset the hardware cost?

I found a table of historical memory prices [1], which claims today DDR4 RAM costs about $0.0027 per MB. Bitcoin currently trades at around 20,000 units of that currency.

As a first approximation each transaction vbyte would fill 1 MB of RAM globally, which would correspond to a fee rate of 0.0027 / 20,000 = 13 sat/vbyte.

However, vbytes are not bytes, only outputs add to the UTXO set size, inputs reduce it. There's some overhead in storing each (relevant) transaction byte in RAM.

[0] having the entire UTXO set in RAM speeds up block processing, though once caught up it's perhaps less useful to do so. So this question may overstate the externality cost a bit. Then again, RAM needs to be replaced every couple of years until the heat death of the universe, discounted by Moore's Law.

[1] https://jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm

Comment: This is a strange question IMO. The fee is not paid to the verifiers who need this RAM. Secondly, pressure on RAM from validatin logic is proportional to rate of UTXO turnover, while fees are proportional to block space usage.